# Session not working on My Web server

Tags: php, session

#### Showing Error

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie -
>   headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php:8) in
>   /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php on line 11
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - >headers already sent (output started at >/home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php:8) in >/home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php on line 11

#### index.php

```
<?php
//simple PHP login script using Session
//start the session * this is important
session_start();

//login script
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'login'){

//give your login credentials here
if($_REQUEST['uname'] != '' && $_REQUEST['pass'] != '')
{
    $email=$_REQUEST['uname'];
    $pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];
    //echo $email.$pass;
    include("db.php");
mysql_query("select * from users where email='$email' and pass='$pass' ");
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
{

$_SESSION['login_user'] = $email;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['login_msg'] = 1;

}
}
else
$_SESSION['login_msg'] = 1;
}

//get the page name where to redirect
if(isset($_REQUEST['pagename']))
$pagename = $_REQUEST['pagename'];

//logout script
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'logout'){
unset($_SESSION['login_user']);
header('Location:index.php');
}
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
if(isset($_REQUEST['pagename']))
{
?>
//header('Location:'.$pagename.'.php');
<script type="text/javascript">
self.location='<?php echo $pagename.'.php';  ?>';
 </script>
<?php
}
else
{
$email=$_REQUEST['uname'];
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    self.location='<?php echo 'home.php';  ?>';
     </script>
    <?php
    }
//header('Location:home.php');
}else{
?>


  <form id="" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="452" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="172">  <input name="uname" type="text" style="margin-top:15px;     width:150px; height:22px;   border:1px solid #CCCCCC; padding-left:30px;" placeholder="Email or Phone" />
</td>
      <td width="177">    <input name="pass" type="password" style=" margin-top:15px;   width:150px; height:22px;   border:1px solid #CCCCCC; padding-left:30px;"   placeholder="Password" />
</td>
      <td width="81"><input name="login" type="submit" style=" margin-top:15px; background-color:#FFFF00;background-color: #fdd922; margin-left:30px;
border: 1px solid #e0bc27; font-weight:bold;
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px; height:25px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,       sans-serif; font-size:12px;  color: #565656;" placeholder="login" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><?php
//display the error msg if the login credentials are wrong!
if(isset($_SESSION['login_msg'])){
echo '<div style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;      color:#F00;">Wrong username and password !</div>';
unset($_SESSION['login_msg']);
}
?>    </td>
      </tr>
  </table>



  <input type="hidden" name="ch" value="login">
  </form>
  </div>
  <?php } 

?>
```

#### home.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

//check logged in or not!
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    ?>
//header('Location:index.php?pagename='.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"));

<script type="text/javascript">
self.location='<?php echo 'index.php?pagename='.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php"); ?    >';
 </script>
<?php
}
else
{
    include("db.php");
$uname=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$q=mysql_query("select * from users where email = '$uname'");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$uid=$r['fname'];

?>
```

Please Help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: The error means there is output before you are starting the session.  It could be a space or new line.

Comment: @mathius1 the code doesn't seems to have any new-line or output before session starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there is no data sent by the server before dealing with Sessions.
This includes White Spaces, Blank Lines or any type of data.

Answer (score 0):

The point where output started is shown in the error message:

```
output started at /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php:8
```

It seems you have a "dispatcher" index.php, which loads other php files (like login.php). The reason for this error is something being printed in index.php on line 8.

If you see nothing printed on index.php, then there might be a newline at the end of file (if you are using Vi, it leaves a trailing new line on every file)

Comment: sorry it's my mistake ... not login.php ... page name was index.php

Comment: Then I guess the code snippet for index.php here is not the one you encountered the error with. Because there is nothing wrong here on line 8 that might cause this issue

Comment: Error with index.php is okey ... but .. session not starting .. I think that's why the home page is redirect to  the index page

Comment: it cannot be ok, it is just hidden

Comment: Ohhhh ..:( .. then what should I do ..??

Comment: In the error message it is stated that session_start is on line 11 and output started on line 8. In given code snippet session_start is on line 4. This inconsistency shows this code snippet is not the one you had the error. I understand you might have modified code before posting here but I need to see what is on line 8 to find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set cookies (or send any other headers) after output is started. You could add

`ob_start()`

at line 1 to buffer the output.

Comment: Thanks alot ... Errors are gone ... :)

Comment: Problem with login page is gone.. but when I login using email id and password .. showing 2 error lines for a second and again redirects to the login page

Comment: @UmairAyub, you identified the reason correctly but suggested a wrong way to fix this issue. ob_start would just hide the actual reason

Comment: I can't read  because it's showing for a second... In home.php

Comment: Is that all your code that you posted in question? Because warning is on line 11 but that seems ok

Comment: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/home.php:54) in /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/home.php on line 55

Comment: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/home.php:54) in /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/home.php on line 55
//header('Location:index.php?pagename='.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"));

Comment: Well, look inside db.php , make sure you don't output anything and there is no newline(blank-space) in before header()

Comment: line number 54 means the first line (<?php)

Comment: <?php
$con = mysql_connect("Server_IP_Address ","allyface","pass");
if(!$con)
{
die("Could not Connect".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("allyface",$con)or die("Could not Connect to the Database".mysql_error());

?>

Comment: Can you provide another login code using session.. thanks in advance

Comment: You have 3 errors in your home.php code you posted in question. Here is the corrected one http://pastebin.com/YR2PYBgy

Comment: again showing these errors in index.php<Warning: session_start()[function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already 'sent by (output started at /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php:8) in /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php on line 10

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php:8) in /home/content/82/11942882/html/praveen/Allyface/index.php on line 10

Comment: ensure that the <?php is the first character, not tabbed or spaced.